# Unlock screen of Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I had fingerprint set to lock Samsung Galaxy S6. I don't remember ever setting a backup password - screen literally locked as I passed the phone to someone.

I managed to access the phone signed in on Google. Then the phone requested I set up another fingerprint lock, which I did. I also put a password in, which I remember. But the password is not being recognised, and the phone is locked again.

- I tried all combinations of all passwords I have, but no luck unlocking the phone
- Samsung's Find My Mobile and Android Device Manager not letting me access phone/reset lock (perhaps because the remote control is not enabled)?
- Unable to install the lock bypass app as it's saying the app is not compatible
- Unable to use ADB
- Tried installing 3rd-party apps to unlock the screen, but they don't work

Desperate to sort this out before I do a factory reset. Samsung Service Centre didn't really help, they said factory reset is the only option.

Any suggestions on how to unlock the phone (or do a data backup before I factory reset) would be great.

Comment: Do you have access to your notification drawer?

Comment: Hi, no I'm unable to access it

Comment: Do you see any type of clickable notification from Play Store when installing an app? Like "XXX has been installed" that you can tap on to launch it in the background? Also, what carrier/network you're on?

Comment: Hi again, and thank you for helping!  When I install an app the notification states that it has been installed, but I can't click on it...it still asks for the backup password.

Comment: i'm on a dubai carrier

Comment: If you have the international S6 you may be able to flash TWRP recovery and at least back up your data. You may also be able to flash a .zip to root your phone and bypass the lockscreen.

Comment: [Here are the instructions](http://www.droidviews.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s6-and-install-twrp-recovery-all-models/) Looks like most of it is Odin you should definitely be able to get your files back! I'll write up a detailed answer in a minute.

Comment: that's fantastic - i will give it a go and let you know how i get on! many thanks again

Comment: I'm getting this message when I try to boot into recovery mode to get into TWRP - Recovery Is not Seandroid Enforcing - i got the pass message on odin, but get stuck with the reboot every time - any suggestions?

Comment: That's a normal message for custom recovery, all my phones say that. So it just gets stuck at that screen? I would recommend flashing something else like CWM or Philz touch. The fact that you got this far is good news. You just need to find a recovery that works with your phone!

Comment: thanks v much  - yes it gets stuck at this screen every time...tried philz touch and cwm...will keep looking for other versions to get it to work!

Comment: Also! If none of the recoveries boot, and you suspect it is because of Selinux Enforcing, just flash a Selinux permissive kernel before flashing the recovery, search "sm g920|925-F|G|H (whatever your part number is) permissive kernel" on Google / XDA. Perhaps [this universal one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/samsung-galaxy-s-6--s-6-edge-unified-development/kernel-stockmod-kernel-t3100395) will work for you!

Comment: If you have TWRP, you can reboot into the phones built-in recovery software. Once you are there you can select recovery. Once in recovery you can make a backup of your data, then you can do a factory reset. I really hope this helped!

Comment: TWRP **is** the recovery. It is a custom one not *built-in*. And in TWRP there isn't a *recovery* button but *backup* and *restore*.

Answer (score 1):

Following [the guide](http://www.droidviews.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s6-and-install-twrp-recovery-all-models/) submitted by Aaron Gillion, when I arrived at the step "6. Go into adb shell type su hit enter" all I kept receiving was:

> CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE DEPENDENCIES: library "libc.so" not found

I fixed it via TWRP → File Manager. I navigated to `/sbin/libc.so` to confirm the file exists, so SuperSU was installed correctly.

So, instead of running the commands:

```
rm /data/system/gesture.key then rm /data/system/password.key
```

I went to TWRP → File Manager, navigated to the location `/data/system/`  and deleted the `fingerprint.key` and `password.key` files

Comment: Good call, you can delete those files directly from TWRP or Aroma File Manager in Philz Touch.

Comment: I can't even run adb shell it pops out 'CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE DEPENDENCIES: library "libc.so" not found'

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out whether you can go all the way and bypass your lock screen will depend on the outcome of the steps below.

Following [this guide](http://www.droidviews.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s6-and-install-twrp-recovery-all-models/),

1. Skip the step of turning on USB Debugging, you can't get past the lockscreen.
2. Download Odin, and the TWRP .tar file
3. Boot your phone to download mode, then plug it in to your computer, let the drivers install. Open the Odin.exe on your computer, fiddle with the USB connection until Odin says "COM1/2/3/4: Connected!"
4. Put the TWRP .tar file in the correct textbox, uncheck Auto-Reboot
5. Flash!
6. When it says finished, you can reboot your phone. **However!** You need to boot it directly into recovery mode, otherwise TWRP gets overridden past the Samsung logo.
7. Once you're in TWRP, congrats! Make a FULL backup onto an SD card or USB drive with OTG adapter.

Now to bypass your lockscreen:

1. Flash the SuperSU .zip found in the guide.
2. When you boot into TWRP does your computer recognize the phone in Device Manager? Does it make a bloop sound? You should find a device called "ADB".
3. Download the ADB kit [from here](http://adbshell.com/downloads) (and the drivers if you can't get your computer to install them) and call `adb.exe` from a command prompt.
4. Run `adb devices`. If you see a long 50-character ID pop up, you're in luck!
5. If there's no ID, try another computer, it took me 5 computers to recognize.
6. Go into `adb shell` type `su` hit enter.
7. If it says permission denied, you're out of luck.
8. Run `rm /data/system/gesture.key` then `rm /data/system/password.key`
9. If no errors, profit!
10. If permission denied, remount system RW: `mount -o rw,remount /system` If that fails, try `mount -o rw,remount /proc /system` (a little hack I came across) and try step 8 again.

Comment: User kumepro had this to add: *"you have to also delete 3 files also "locksettings.db" "locksettings.db-wal" "locksettings.db-shm"*.